# Problems with rosinstall on MAC OSX 10.5

Tags: ros, cturtle, rosinstall, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, When I try to install ros by following the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/OSX), I get this error :

```
$ rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=cturtle&variant=base&overlay=no"

/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.5.egg/rosinstall/vcs/svn.py:49: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 442, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1167, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 28, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.5.egg/rosinstall/vcs/svn.py", line 49
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as fnull:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have python 2.5:

```
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 11 sep  2010 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python
```

I found the same problem happend on debian - [link](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rosinstall-problems-on-Debian-td2492092.html)

How can I solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10641/problems-with-rosinstall-on-mac-osx-10.5/) by [gwilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/855/gwilly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get this to work on python 2.5 you need to add

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

at the top of the rosinstall script.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1